# Algebra Parameters

Tags: linear-algebra

I got 4 equations, where are $x,y,z,u$ variables , and $a,b$ parameters. So the solution from the book is like this:

$$x+(a+1)y-(a+1)z-au=1$$

$$ax+(a+1)y+az-2u=2$$

$$ax+(a+1)y-2z+au=b$$

$$(a-1)x+3(a+1)z-4u=3-b$$

So when I do all transformations it gets this form:

$$(a+1)y+x-(a+1)z-au=1$$

$$(a-1)x+(2a+1)z+(a-2)u=1$$

$$(-a-2)z+(a+2)u=b-2$$

Now, next steps are these:

1. If $a\neq-1 , a\neq1 , a\neq-2$: System is indefinite
2. If $a=-1$: System is indefinite
3. If $a=1$: System is indefinite
4. If $a=-2$: System can be either indefinite or impossible

My question is how did we got that first part where $a$ can't be $1, -1$ or $-2$. Why it can be $2$ or $0$ or some other number?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a_{i,j}, b_k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I will talk about what you have. I do not know if your computations are OK (I think they are not).

In your case, you have done changes and you have obtained:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&a+1&a+1&-a\\ a-1&0&2a+1&a-2\\0&0&-a-2&a+2\\0&0&0&0\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\z\\u\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\b-2\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

That is telling you that you have a degree of freedom since you have $4$ variables and $3$ equations. Hence, one of your variables will depend of the others. Hence, the system will have infinite solutions. Hence it is 'indefinite'. But you have got that it is indefinite for all $a$. (Since you got this reduction for all $a$ and there is a $1$ that will never be zero. Then you will never have a zero matrix for any $a$.)(Changing values of $a$ you may get more zero rows but it will be still 'indefinite' since you can not make a whole row zero with a fixed value of $a$.).

Moreover,a system like
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}&a_{1,3}&a_{1,4}\\ a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&a_{2,3}&a_{2,4}\\a_{3,1}&a_{3,2}&a_{3,3}&a_{3,4}\\a_{4,1}&a_{4,2}&a_{4,3}&a_{4,4}\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\z\\u\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}b_1\\ b_2\\b_3\\b_4\end{bmatrix}$$

is an 'impossible' system or has no solution when you find that a whole row of $a_{i,j}$ is zero for a fixed $i$ and the respective $b_i$ is not zero.

In your case, you have done changes and you have obtained:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&a+1&a+1&-a\\ a-1&0&2a+1&a-2\\0&0&-a-2&a+2\\0&0&0&0\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\z\\u\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\b-2\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

And that is not 'impossible'.

**HINT:**

1. Try to put your system this way.
2. Reduce it until you get an upper triangular matrix.

When you get something like:

$$\begin{bmatrix}b_{1,1}&b_{1,2}&b_{1,3}&b_{1,4}\\ 0&b_{2,2}&b_{2,3}&b_{2,4}\\0&0&b_{3,3}&b_{3,4}\\0&0&0&b_{4,4}\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\z\\u\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}c_1\\ c_2\\c_3\\c_4\end{bmatrix}$$

you will see that $b_{4,4}$ and $c_4$ will be certain expressions.

If $b_{4,4} = 0$ and $c_4=0$, the system will be 'indefinite'.

If $b_{4,4} \neq 0$, you will be able to find $u$ and solve your system. And it will have a unique solution.

If $b_{4,4} = 0$ and $c_4\neq 0$, the system will be 'impossible'.